# Why the animation does not reset

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

I can't figure out why the animation does not reset. I want to keep animation like the first time you click, but after clicking once the animation is breaking

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-spring-pj4jzs?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A36%2C38&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clta34pxo0006356k41ji3pai%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clta34pxn0002356kucrqgvng%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clta34pxn0003356kdaldya1h%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clta34pxn0005356kdx6g6k2x%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B52.50814332247557%252C47.49185667752443%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clta34pxn0002356kucrqgvng%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clta34pxn0002356kucrqgvng%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltbbr79s0002356kbq02zmfz%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A36%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A38%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A36%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A38%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltbbr79s0002356kbq02zmfz%2522%257D%252C%2522clta34pxn0005356kdx6g6k2x%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clta34pxn0005356kdx6g6k2x%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clta34pxn0004356kc4g16qza%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clta34pxn0004356kc4g16qza%2522%257D%252C%2522clta34pxn0003356kdaldya1h%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clta34pxn0003356kdaldya1h%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A0%257D)
I want to keep repeating the initial animation. I tried reset, but it does not work.